# Covering map and the commutant, wedge sum of circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I have the following problem to solve.

Find a covering of $S^1\vee S^1$ corresponding to the commutant of $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)$.

Ok, we know (I do more or less) that the universal cover of this bouquet of circles is Cayley graph, which can be represented as generated by two elements $a,b$ (up,down) on a plane with every step of half of length of before one.

$\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)=\mathbb{Z}\star\mathbb{Z}=<a,b>$

I think that the only elements that commute with $\mathbb{Z}\star\mathbb{Z}$ are loops of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, but that's the smallest one. We alse have loops of different shapes and length. I claim that these are elements of the commutator, but  I have difficulties with formalizing it and finishing..

In the end I would divide $\pi_1$ of this group by the commutator and consider what kind  of space could it be..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let $F = \pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ be the free group on two generators.  If by commutant you mean the commutator subgroup $[F,F]$, then you're just looking for the abelianization $F/[F,F]$ of $F$, which is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, the free abelian group on two generators.  (One cheap way to see this is to note that the abelianization of $\pi_1$ is $H_1$.)

Consider the Cayley graph of $F$.  By quotienting out the commutator subgroup, we are identifying the endpoint of the path $a^n b^m$ with the endpoint of the path $b^m a^n$. If I'm not mistaken, this turns out to give the space obtained by the "integral lattice grid" in $\mathbb{R}^2$. One way to see this is the answer is to note that this cover is regular and its Deck group is precisely $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.  See exercise 1.3.18 in Hatcher's *Algebraic topology*.